# Simple Bing News Search Api - Search for Phrase

Tags: bing, bing-api

I want to search for a phrase and not the collection of words How can I do this?

For instance 
"&Query= Widget Foo"

I only want to return results with the phrase 'Widget Foo' and not widget separate from foo.

Comment: Worth adding here that this method is DEPRECATED.  You have to use the Azure Data Market version of Bing Search now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your search term in quotes. Here is an example that is already url encoded:

```
http://www.bing.com/search?q=%22widget+foo%22
```

Answer (score 0):

Same principle applies to phrases searched for with the Bing API's subscription model at:

https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search

So if you're looking for the news phrase:

"Palin mocks Obama and Rove in CPAC speech"

..wrap your query in quotes and URL encode the quotes as well:

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=%27%22Palin%20mocks%20Obama%20and%20Rove%20in%20CPAC%20speech%22%27